# How do I add a module to a block/region in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How do I add a module to a block/region in Drupal 7?

I am starting to format my Drupal 7 site to look like I want it do.

I have an empty block on the home page on the right side that I want to put a module in.  I am thinking about a nice accordion menu or tree menu.  How do I add a module to a block in Drupal 7?

I am new to Drupal and so I am probably confusing terminologies here.

If I click on Structure -> Blocks in the admin panel I am taken to a page where blocks are assigned to regions

[image]

If I click on the hyperlink to "Demonstrate block regions (Porto)", I am shown a page that represents regions (I guess) on the page as yellow fields/blocks and the name assigned to each of them.  This is what I am referring to as "blocks" and I suppose this is a misnomer.

[image]

Earlier, I was trying to find a way of changing the width of a of a MD Slider and no matter what I tried in the configuration of this (Module?) nothing seemed to work.  But then I noticed that could assign this to the "Content" area on the page and put something else in the "Right Sidebar" and this trick managed to change the layout of the page closer to what I was looking for like this:

[image]

and the result of my efforts is a home page that looks like this:

[image]

Which is getting close to how I want the home page to be arranged.  Here, as an example, this is the previous layout I had before switching to the current theme:

[image]

Notice the "Navagation" UI control on the right side.  This is what I am talking about here.  If I add a module, like a tree or accordian, how do I get this to be put in the  Blocks page such that it can be added to the region I want, which is the "Right Sidebar"?

Comment: Drupal terminology uses *module* to refer to pieces of code that extend base functionality - there are core, contributed and custom modules - dont' use the word  "module" if you are not talking about this in the drupal world, it can be misleading. A theme defines the page layout, which is composed of regions, and each region can be assigned some content, or *block(s)*. You can assign the "Navigation" block to the "right sidebar" region, you can also alter it to better fit your need, but you can also provide your own custom block. Is your question "how to create a custom block ?"

Comment: You would [create a custom block](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/declaring-the-block) in a custom module.